# xsd custom decimal type definition, not zero

Tags: xsd, decimal, restriction

I would like to define a XSD type which is a decimal (positive or negative) but it cannot be zero. How can I do it?

This is the body of definition:

```
<simpleType name="grossValueType">
<restriction base="decimal">
<!-- What put here? -->
</restriction>
</simpleType>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define two types, negativeDecimals and positiveDecimals, and then union them together to get what you want:

```
<xs:simpleType name="negativeDecimals">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:maxExclusive value="0"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="positiveDecimals">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:minExclusive value="0"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:element name="measure">
    <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:union memberTypes="negativeDecimals positiveDecimals"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Since neither base type can accept 0, that value will be illegal; all other decimal values will be legal.